# Format of HTML tables with `printr` package

Tags: html, css, r, rstudio, knitr

I've just started using the `printr` package (https://github.com/yihui/printr) within RStudio (0.98.1103, OS X). It works excellently to generate nicely formatted (centred) tables when generating PDFs (`Knit PDF` button). With `Knit HTML` the table are spread across the full width of the page ( browser or viewer) regardless of the number of columns -- I'd like the tables centred, as they appear in the `printr` vignette (http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knit_print.html). Is this a CSS issue, or am I missing a simple 'trick'?

Thanks

Comment: I solved this by noticing that the printr vignette source has this in the header: `output:
  knitr:::html_vignette:`.

Answer (score 1):

The centering is accomplished via CSS.  In particular, this bit in the CSS link sets the left and right margins to `auto` which makes the (fixed-width) table centered in the column.

```
table:not([class]) {
  margin: auto auto 10px auto;
}
```